# using captcha in mobile apps

Tags: android, mobile, captcha, recaptcha

I am looking for an alternative for captcha to use in our mobile applications. We are writing a mobile application in iOS and Android. The web application is already exist. In the web page we are using captcha to ensure only genuine customers are applying and to prevent denial of service type attacks.

So from mobile app also we need to take care of these. Any body came across the same situation? Is it recommended to use captcha in native mobile apps?

Comment: I fail to see how CAPTCHAs have anything to do with "denial of service type attacks". Attackers do not need to access post-authentication pages to implement a DoS attack. "So from mobile app also we need to take care of these" -- why? Name any professional Android app that requires people use a CAPTCHA. I certainly have not seen any, from the likes of Google, Twitter, Evernote, Stack Overflow, TripIt, etc.

Comment: I belief it depends on the architecture of the web services. If the serives have proper authentication mechanism like oath, then it may not required. But in this case the service architecture is not like that.

Answer (score 3):

A mechanism to prevent automated traffic must definitely be used. Not doing so means you will allow a way to access your servers which can be automated. Even though you might think it is only available from mobile apps, an attacker code can run anywhere and bring your system to halt.

If your concern is that captchas will be inconvenient to mobile users, try google Recaptcha. Where usually its a click of checkbox or clicking some images in some cases where google is not able to determine based on the checkbox.

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Answer (score 2):

## There is a library for android using google recaptcha
https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA
Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA

[image: Download] [image: Build Status] [image: CircleCI] [image: Codeship Status for ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA] [image: Build Status]  [image: BuddyBuild]

The reCAPTCHA Android Library provides a simple way to show a [CAPTCHA](https://web.archive.org/web/20140219233532/http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) as an `ImageView` in your Android app, helping you stop bots from abusing it. The library wraps the [reCAPTCHA API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro).

[image: Screenshot]

### Quick Start

First you have to [sign up for your API keys](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin).

**Installation**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'android.lib.recaptcha:reCAPTCHA:+'
}
```

**The Layout**

To show CAPTCHA image, you need to add a `<android.lib.recaptcha.ReCaptcha />` element to your layout XML:

```
android.lib.recaptcha.ReCaptcha
android:id="@+id/recaptcha"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="centerInside" /&gt;
```

It is important to use `android:scaleType="centerInside"` to ensure the entire [CAPTCHA](https://web.archive.org/web/20140219233532/http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) image can be displayed.

Alternatively, you can create an instance of `android.lib.recaptcha.ReCaptcha` at runtime:

```
ReCaptcha reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha(context);
```

**How to show CAPTCHA**

In your activity/fragment/view containing `android.lib.recaptcha.ReCaptcha`, you need display a [CAPTCHA](https://web.archive.org/web/20140219233532/http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) image for the user to response:

```
ReCaptcha reCaptcha = (ReCaptcha)findViewById(R.id.recaptcha);
reCaptcha.showChallengeAsync("your-public-key", onShowChallengeListener);
```

`showChallengeAsync` downloads and shows [CAPTCHA](https://web.archive.org/web/20140219233532/http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) image asynchronously. It is safe to invoke in UI thread. No exception will be thrown in case of any error by this call. All errors will be treated as unsuccessful in showing [CAPTCHA](https://web.archive.org/web/20140219233532/http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) image.

`onShowChallengeListener` is an instance of `ReCaptcha.OnShowChallengeListener`, which is called when an attempt to show a [CAPTCHA](https://web.archive.org/web/20140219233532/http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) is completed.

The synchronous version of this method is `showChallenge`.

**How to verify user input**

To verify user input, pass the input string to `ReCaptcha.verifyAnswerAsync` (or `ReCaptcha.verifyAnswer`):

```
reCaptcha.verifyAnswerAsync("your-private-key", "user-input", onVerifyAnswerListener);
```

`verifyAnswerAsync` asynchronously submits the user input string to reCAPTCHA server for verification. It is safe to invoke in UI thread. No exception will be thrown in case of any error by this call. All errors will be treated as verification failure.

`onVerifyAnswerListener` is an instance of `ReCaptcha.OnVerifyAnswerListener`, which is called when an attempt to verify the user input is completed.

The synchronous version of this method is `verifyAnwser`.

**Specify a locale**

You can force the widget to render in a specific language. Please refer to [this page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/language).

```
reCaptcha.setLanguageCode("fr");
```

### Sample Application

A complete sample application is available at https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA/tree/master/reCAPTCHA-Samples.

Comment: Please see [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). *Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it.*